# Spring boot entitymanager update query postgress get result back

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am using spring boot and postgress database.
I am executing below native query which returns code (string):

```
String query = update a1 set item_id=10, order_id=20 where id=(select id from a1 where c=10 and order_id is null 
               limit 1) returning code

 Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery(query);
 q.getSingleResult(); // not working as only work with select statement
 q.executeUpdate(); // returns only count of updated row.
```

so, how to get result back in above query?

Comment: That's not possible with JPA

Comment: Even not possible with JDBC template or any other way?

Comment: Sure with JDBC this works. Or even better with https://jooq.org.